# Spark returns an array of null values when select sub-entities

Tags: apache-spark

I have an entity:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "col_1": null,
  "sub_entities": [
    { "sub_entity_id": "s-1", "col_2": null },
    { "sub_entity_id": "s-2", "col_2": null }
  ]
}
```

and I loaded it to spark: `val entities = spark.read.json("...")`.

`entities.filter(size($"sub_entities.col_2") === 0)` returns nothing. The behavior seems weird because all the `col_2` are null but the null value is counted.

I then tried select `col_2` and noticed it returns an array of null values (2 null values in this case).

```
entities.select($"col_1", $"sub_entities.col_2").show(false)

+--------+------------------+                        
|col_1   |sub_entities.col_2|
+--------+------------------+
|null    |[,]               |
+--------+------------------+
```

How to write a query that returns only objects from the array where col_2 is not null?

Comment: What does it mean to filter out `null` values in this context? Do you want that array above to be returned as empty? Do you want the `sub_entities` to return only objects from the array where  `col_2 is not null`? Please write down the expected output.

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic Edited the question, I want a query to return objects from the array where `col_2` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query **`array`** objects we need to first flatten out the array using **`explode`** function then query the dataframe!

**`Example:`**

```
val df=spark.read.json(Seq("""{"id": "123","col_1": null,"sub_entities": [  { "sub_entity_id": "s-1", "col_2": null },  { "sub_entity_id": "s-2", "col_2": null }]}""").toDS)

df.selectExpr("explode(sub_entities)","*").select("col.*","id","col_1").show()

//+-----+-------------+---+-----+
//|col_2|sub_entity_id| id|col_1|
//+-----+-------------+---+-----+
//| null|          s-1|123| null|
//| null|          s-2|123| null|
//+-----+-------------+---+-----+

df.selectExpr("explode(sub_entities)","*").select("col.*","id","col_1").filter(col("col_2").isNull).show()

//+-----+-------------+---+-----+
//|col_2|sub_entity_id| id|col_1|
//+-----+-------------+---+-----+
//| null|          s-1|123| null|
//| null|          s-2|123| null|
//+-----+-------------+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

This filters out only the array of `col_2` as you mentioned, if you need different output when you do `df.select($"col_1", $"sub_entities").show`, I can update the answer:

```
val json =  
"""
{
    "id": "123",
    "col_1": null,
    "sub_entities": [
        { "sub_entity_id": "s-1", "col_2": null },
        { "sub_entity_id": "s-2", "col_2": null }
    ]
}
"""
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(json).toDS)

val removeNulls = udf((arr : Seq[String]) => arr.filter((x: String) => x != null))
df.select($"col_1", removeNulls($"sub_entities.col_2").as("sub_entities.col_2")).show(false)

+-----+------------------+
|col_1|sub_entities.col_2|
+-----+------------------+
|null |[]                |
+-----+------------------+
```